# Update Maven dependency version in multiple ServiceMix POMs

Tags: maven, fuseesb, apache-servicemix

I am trying to automate process of changing version of a product that has ServiceMix (FuseESB) as an integration module.

Changing the version in each POM is quite easy with the Maven versions plugin:

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=NEW_VERSION -DgenerateBackupPoms=false
```

However, I am now struggling with updating version in dependencies that are other modules of this product. Particularly, in many Service Units' POM files there are dependencies like these (where OLD_VERSION is the same, older version number):

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.company.department.product.module1</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact1</artifactId>
    <version>OLD_VERSION</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.company.department.product.module1</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact2</artifactId>
    <version>OLD_VERSION</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.company.department.product.module2</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact3</artifactId>
    <version>OLD_VERSION</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And I would like to set the version number in those dependencies to "NEW_VERSION".

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: The goal `set` is intended for changing the version of the project but not for the dependencies..Can you show an example of your project? Apart from that have you defined the versions in a dependencyManagement part ? Do you use a parent pom for this?

Comment: Use a tool to search/replace in text files (pom.xml files) is also very easy to use, where you can search for the pattern `<version>X</version>` and the replace with `<version>NEW</version>`.

Answer (score 0):

Just found very simple solution for this - replace dependencies' version with ${project.version} - works for me because in my project the dependencies have the same version as the project itself (they are all artifacts of the same product).